# How to replace custom text from a predefined list using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have list of special character

```
const charlist ={'a' : '', 'b' : '', 'c' : '', 'd' : '', }
```

The result I want is when I press key "a" at input text box i should get "" how I can achieve this?

Comment: How you are taking input, in a textarea or input or what? Can you show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below answer is suitable for you.

```js
const charlist ={'a' : '', 'b' : '', 'c' : '', 'd' : '', };
let valueArray=[];

function test(param){
  let value=document.getElementById(param).value;
  valueArray=value.split('');
  let replacedArray=[];
  if(value){
    for(i=0;i<valueArray.length;i++){
      replacedArray.push(filtered(valueArray[i]));
    }
 document.getElementById('output'+param).innerHTML=replacedArray.join('');
  }

}
function filtered(val){
Object.keys(charlist).filter((key)=>
{
  if(key==val){
    val=charlist[key]
  }
}); 
    return val;
}
```

```html
Every Letter Click the output triggered
<input onkeyup=test('a') id="a"></input>
<b>output a :</b><strong id="outputa"></strong>
<br />

<br />
After leave the textbox output triggered
<input onchange=test('b') id="b"></input>
<b>output b :</b><strong id="outputb"></strong>
```

Thank you.

Comment: thank you, I want change in input at same time , not separate Output a & b

Comment: @shrikanthanayak `document.getElementById(param).value=replacedArray.join('');` add this line after the loop , you can solve the cursor problem in id 'b' , because that input triggered in onchange like after leaved the text box.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way of doing it:

```js
const charlist ={'a' : '', 'b' : '', 'c' : '', 'd' : '', };

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 ev.target.value=ev.target.value.split("").map(c=>charlist[c]??c).join("");
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Triggered by any type of input event on the input element I take the whole value of that element, split it into an array and replace any character in it by its `charlist` correspondence. If it doesn't exist, then the character `c` remains unchanged.

Comment: @Carsten Massmann From my understanding, in this each time it will convert every character, Instead of that we can take entered character and convert the character and replace, like taking the last character in value and replace it with the character in list. Can you please tell, Which approach is better and preferable. Correct me if i am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: sir, if i enter a letter in the middle of string cursor goes end of the string, can u help me how to edit string in middle and cursor should hold it its position where letter edited.

Comment: You are too much fixated on your input method: letters are not necessarily entered by keyboard and not necessarily at the end of the string. Yes, I _could_ write a script that reacts on `keyup` and I could try and find the current position in the string do the replacement there, but it will end in a mess of difficult to read code that will still fail when I paste stuff in there with a mouse click! Javascript is sufficiently fast to enable the repeated processing of the whole text without problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is extract the value from charList that's corresponding to the value of user input. In this case,

```
input //key from user input

var specialChar = charList[input]
```

You can then insert the specialChar into the text. Repeat this for every user input.